# Manejo de texto en las vistas de Java

Tags: java, android

En Android hay un manejo de los textos y las vistas relacionándolos en "values/strings.xml". Para facilitar traducciones y reutilización de texto, la pregunta es:

¿Cómo implementar algo similar en proyectos Java de escritorio?

Agradezco desde ya el interés.

Answer (score 1):

Desconozco si haya una forma directa para la traducción en java, pero una solución puede ser con clases estáticas. por ejemplo

```
public class Espanyol {
  static final Map<String , String> PALABRAS = new HashMap<String , String>() {{
    put("Hello",    "Hola");
    put("World", "Mundo");
  }};
}
```

Lo mismo para el ingles

```
public class ingles{
  static final Map<String , String> PALABRAS = new HashMap<String , String>() {{
    put("Hello",    "Hello");
    put("World", "World");
  }};
}
```

Luego creas una clase que es la que va a identificar el idioma

```
public class Traduccion {
  private idioma;
  public Traduccion(string idioma) {
    this.idioma = idioma;
  }
}

public string palabra(String key) {
  if(idioma.equals("es")) {
    return Espanyol.PALABRAS.get(key);
  } else {
    return Ingles.PALABRAS.get(key);
}
```

en tu clase tendrías que crear el objeto traducción y pasarle el idioma.

```
Traduccion t = new Traduccion("es");
System.out.println(t.palabra("Hello") + t.palabra("world"));
```

Esto te imprimiría hola mundo, si cambias la etiqueta te imprimiría hello world

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un archivo de propiedades como te lo muestro en el siguiente ejemplo :

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Sample 
{

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Locale español = new Locale("es");
        printProperty(español);

        Locale ingles = new Locale("en");
        printProperty(ingles);
    }

    public static void printProperty(Locale locale)
    {
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("propiedades", locale);
        System.out.println(rb.getString("idioma"));
        System.out.println(rb.getString("nombre"));
        System.out.println(rb.getString("mensaje"));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

tu estructura del proyecto debe verse asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi es cada archivo de propiedades(los debes crear como new -> file)

Propiedades_es.properties :

```
idioma:español
nombre:Charbel
mensaje:mensaje de prueba
```

Propiedades_en.properties :

```
idioma:ingles
nombre:Charbel
mensaje:sample message
```